# Load cell and hx711 with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I wanted to connect the load cell with hx711 to Arduino to check the presence of load. If there is load on the load cell then an LED can light up and when there is no load the LED will be off. I tried several codes but I'm not getting the result I need. If anyone of you can help with this as this is for my graduation project I will be grateful.

EDIT:

Here is my code, I'm a beginner in Arduino so I don't know much about how it works but this is what I managed to write. PS. the hashtaq before include makes the the text in bold so I excluded it here.

```
include < HX711_ADC.h >

HX711_ADC scale (2,3); //DT pin2 , SCK pin3 
int load1 =0;

void setup() { 
   pinMode (3,INPUT); // SCK pin 
   pinMode (13,OUTPUT); //LED pin 
   Serial.begin(9600); }

void loop() { 
   load1= digitalRead(3); // read signal from SCK pin

   if(load1==HIGH) // if there is load on load cell 
        { 
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // turn on the LED 
        delay(5000); 
   } else {
       digitalWrite(13,LOW); // turn off the LED 
       delay(5000); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: This isn't a forum. Don't respond to questions with an "answer". Amend your question.

Comment: @bummi - Whoops sorry for the rejection, didn't realise that the edit was from the answer. My bad.

Comment: look at the line starting with `void setup()` ... everything after the `; //` all way to end of line is a `comment` .... it is not code that executes .... same goes for the two lines after that .... please correct the code listing

Comment: You are not using the https://github.com/bogde/HX711 library properly.  Instead of `load1=digitalRead(3);` try something like `load1 = scale.get_units();` (and initlialize the scale with a `scale.begin()` in setup and maybe a `scale.tare()` )